# Bounded in probability and finite expectation

Tags: asymptotics, bounds

Let $x_t = O_p(1)$, meaning that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $M_{\varepsilon} < \infty$ s.t. $P(|X_t| > M_{\varepsilon}) < \epsilon$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Does it imply that $\sup_{t} Ex_t < \infty$, namely, whether the expectation of a random variable which is bounded in probability is finite. If it is not the case, could you give me a  counter example?

Comment: Could you please explain your notation?  It could mean practically anything... .

Comment: I tried to make it more understandable. I don't really understand where is a problem, since I used a standard notation, I am sorry about it.

Comment: Thanks.  The appearance of $p$ and $t$ as subscripts is mystifying: do these have any meaning?

Comment: A subscript $p$ is for bounded in PROBABILITY, $t$ is just an index, since I am considering time series, but it is not very important. I made it explicit. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: I believe $t$ is *essential,* for otherwise it looks like you are merely asking for an example of a [random variable whose expectation is not defined](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=undefined%20expectation). Indeed, it is difficult to see how your question differs substantially from that.  With the introduction of the index $t$, it is crucial that you supply a *quantifier* in your statement: do you mean *there exists* a $t$ for which $x_t$ has finite expectation or *for all* $t$ the expectation should be finite, or perhaps for *infinitely many* or *almost all* $t$?

Comment: I added supremum. Since I am talking about uniform boundnedness, probably it makes more sence. In the very beginning I wanted to ask only about boundnedness of one variable, not uniform boundnedness, but I recognised that for my problem I need uniform boundnedness.

Comment: The existence of a random variable with undefined expectation still makes the question (as stated) of little interest: just set all the $x_t$ equal to such an RV. You refer to "my problem:" why not post *that* instead of trying to fix up this abstract question, since the fixups don't seem to be going anywhere useful?

Comment: I don't think that this exactly refers to "your problem". I am talking about a random variable which satisfies some conditions, namely, is bounded in probability, not about an arbitrary random variable.

Comment: *All* random variables that take real values are "bounded in probability" according to your definition.  (I am excluding technical applications in which values of "$\pm\infty$" may be allowed.) This follows directly from the axioms of probability

Comment: Thus, boundnedness in probability does not imply that the expectation is finite and my problem is solved. I know how to construct an example of variable which has the undefinite expectation. Am I right stating that in my definition it is the case because $M$ depends on $\varepsilon$? Is it true that if $M$ does not depend on $\varepsilon$, $P(|X_t| > M) < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ is equivalent to $P(|X_t| > M)  = 0$?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a counter example. Let $X_{n}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, be
a sequence of random variables, whose distributions are defined as
follows,
$$
X_{n}=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{with probability }\frac{n-1}{n},\\
n^{2}, & \mbox{with probability }\frac{1}{n}.
\end{cases}
$$
To see $X_{n}\sim O_{p}\left(1\right)$, let $\varepsilon>0$ be an
arbitrary positive number, and there exists $M_{\varepsilon}=\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}+1\right\rfloor ^{2}$
($\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}\right\rfloor $ is the integer part
of $\varepsilon^{-1}$) such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sup_{n}\Pr\left(\left|X_{n}\right|\geq M_{\varepsilon}\right) & = & \Pr\left(X_{\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}+1\right\rfloor }=\left(\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}+1\right\rfloor \right)^{2}\right)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\left\lfloor \varepsilon^{-1}+1\right\rfloor }\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
However, $\mathrm{{E}}\left(X_{n}\right)=n$ by the design, and $\sup_{n}\mathrm{{E}}X_{n}=\infty$.

Intuitively, 'bounded in probability' only restricts the probability placed on the extreme values; it does not say anything about the ratio between the extreme value and its associated probability. I hope this example could clarify something for your problem.